# What is the exact description of the homogeneous Besov space $\smash{\dot{B}}^0_{1,1}(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, besov-spaces

The Besov space is defined briefly in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Besov_space) and I looked for a number of references to find some information on the homogeneous Besov space $\smash{\dot{B}}^0_{1,1}(\mathbb{R})$.

However, essentially every embedding theorem excludes the case $B^{s}_{p,q}$ with $p=q=1$….

For example, does $\smash{\dot{B}}^0_{1,1}(\mathbb{R})$ coincide with $L^1(\mathbb{R})$? Or what is the relation between the norm $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{B^0_{1,1}}$ and $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{L^1}$?

I rummaged through all relevant references but cannot find any information at all. It is unbearably elusive…. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: $\newcommand\d{\dot}$TeX note: $\d{B^0_{1, 1}}$ `\dot{B^0_{1, 1}}` centres the dot over the entire expression $B^0_{1, 1}$.  $\d B^0_{1, 1}$ `\dot B^0_{1, 1}` puts it in the proper place, but, as discussed in my [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1169571) on your other [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452275), it's too tall. $\smash{\d B}^0_{1, 1}$ `\smash{\dot B}^0_{1, 1}` *does* work, and I have edited accordingly. \\ Did you mean $\lVert\cdot\rVert_{\smash{\d B}^0_{1, 1}}$ in place of $\lVert\cdot\rVert_{B^0_{1, 1}}$?

Comment: @LSpice oh yes...I am very sorry for the confusion..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find definitions and results about homogeneous Besov spaces in ["Fourier Analysis and Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-16830-7). Here are the general relations with Lp

[image]

and
[image]

So $\dot{B}^{0}_{1,1}$ is inside $L^{1}$. This just follows from Bernstein’s lemma.

For anyone interested, it would be nice to type the definitions in the wikipedia article for Besov space.

Comment: Thank you so much...Could you perhaps help me with the following question as well: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452275/validity-of-holder-inequality-for-the-homogeneous-besov-spaces-dotb0-1-2?

Comment: I think there are so many equivalent descriptions of the Besov spaces, and the Wikipedia definition is not that elegant...Moreover, I don't think I am suficiently skilled in this area to write down a good definition myself.