# Validity of Hölder inequality for the homogeneous Besov spaces $\dot{B}^0_{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\dot{B}^0_{2,2}(\mathbb{R}^n)=L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, inequalities, sobolev-spaces, besov-spaces

I am looking at Corollary 1. in  p.244-245 of the book
"[Sobolev Spaces of Fractional Order,
Nemytskij Operators,
and Nonlinear
Partial Differential Equations](https://doi.org/10.1515/9783110812411)" (1996) by Thomas Runst
Winfried Sickel.

There, it is stated that for $1< p_1, p_2 < \infty$ such that $p^{-1}=p_1^{-1}+p_2^{-1}<1$, we have
\begin{equation}
\lVert fg \rVert_{B^0_{p, q}(\mathbb{R}^n)} \leq \lVert f \rVert_{B^0_{p_1, q_1}(\mathbb{R}^n)}\lVert g \rVert_{B^0_{p_1, q_1}(\mathbb{R}^n)}
\end{equation}
if and only if
$q_1 \leq \min\{p_1, 2\}$, $q_2 \leq \min\{p_2,2\}$ and $q \geq \max\{p,2\}$. Here $B^{s}_{p,q}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the Besov space.

Now, I wonder if this inequality also holds valid even when $p=1$, $q=q_1=q_2=p_1=p_2=2$ and all the Besov spaces are "homogeneous". In other words, is the following inequality:
\begin{equation}
\lVert fg \rVert_{\smash{\dot{B}}^0_{1, 2}(\mathbb{R}^n)} \leq \lVert f \rVert_{\smash{\dot{B}}^0_{2, 2}(\mathbb{R}^n)}\lVert g \rVert_{\smash{\dot{B}}^0_{2, 2}(\mathbb{R}^n)}=\lVert f \rVert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}\lVert g \rVert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}
\end{equation}
true? I used the fact that $\smash{\dot{B}}^{0}_{2,2}(\mathbb{R}^n)=L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

This borderline case is NOT considered explicitly in the aforementioned reference, so I am very curious…. Could anyone please clarify for me?

Comment: TeX note: $\dot B$ is a taller box than $B$ alone, so the superscript lands in the wrong place: $\dot B^0 B^0$.  You can force TeX to ignore the actual height of a box by using `\smash`, which puts the superscript in the proper place: $\smash{\dot B}^0 B^0$ `\smash{\dot B}^0 B^0`.  I have done so, except in the title, where there wasn't room.

Comment: Oh thank you for your tips.

Comment: @LSpice could you provide the answer as well?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452275/validity-of-h%c3%b6lder-inequality-for-the-homogeneous-besov-spaces-dotb0-1-2#comment1169587_452275), no, unfortunately I do not know the answer.

Comment: I think the estimate you are looking for is true. Writing the Bony decomposition, and standard Hölder inequalities, it should be fair to obtain such inequality. I didn't check the full details.
However, you can find a weaker version available from the book of Bahouri, Chemin and Danchin (pages 86-97) with an embedding in the Besov space $\smash{\dot{\mathrm{B}}}^{0}_{1,\infty}$ or in $\smash{\dot{\mathrm{B}}}^{-n/2}_{2,1}$. Paraproduct estimates for homogeneous Besov spaces can be found in many papers written by people from the French school of fluid dynamics (Charve, Chemin, Danchin, etc.).